# Wolframalpha API

Tags: python-3.x, wolframalpha

I am using the WolframAlpha API. Everything is working fine until I try to get the result of a question. When I ask it "What is the meaning of life" instead of the program giving me `42`, it gives me "`42  s`"... Not too sure why, could anyone help?

This is my code:

```
import wolframalpha
client= wolframalpha.Client("**myappid**")
z = "What is the meaning of life?"
res = client.query(z)
try:
    print (next(res.results).text)
except StopIteration:
    print ("No results")
```

Comment: Your code as-is prints: 42 (according to the book The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, by Douglas Adams)

Comment: When I run it the result pod does not contain that, it contains "42 s". When I ask it other things, it adds random things to the answer.

Comment: Perhaps add: &includepodid=Result to the query to narrow in on just the answer/result pod.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    import wolframplha

    app_id = "your app id"

    client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

    res = client.query(input)
    answer = next(res.results).text #to make sure wolramalpha gives answer in text and not in graph and all

    print(answer)
```

Comment: This is python 3.x so the `print answer` is invalid